# How to find and remove duplicate image texture files

Tags: materials

I have a kit with a lot of models and a couple of dozen textures. If I browse the blender file in the Outliner some images are listed as xxx.jpg and xxx.jpg.001 so I’m assuming they are duplicates and wish to get rid of them. If I open one of the .001 files in the image editor it indicates that it has no users, but I can find a material that is using that file in the shader editor. Is there any reliable way to determine if an image actually has no users. I’m hoping to avoid having to manually go through every texture and reassign the non .001 version of the image to the Image Texture node.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the drop down in the outliner to view the blend file and then use the purge button to clear out any you aren't using.

[image: Orphan Data]

If you want to keep something, you can fake a user by clicking the **X**, which will turn to a power button icon.

Comment: Thanks, that could be useful, but in this case none of the duplicate images are listed under orphan data. However there are no duplicate materials, so I'm wondering if it's possible that a material on two different objects can in fact be using different image textures, even if they are duplicates of the same image. I would have thought not.

Comment: I just tested this with a couple of textures and it seems to work well.  Note if a material is orphaned itself, any textures it uses are not orphans, they still belong to the material.  I guess you could always backup your blend file to be safe  then see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer on BA:

Switch the Outliner display mode to ‘Blender File’, expand ‘Images’, select all .00x images, right click, Remap Users, pick the non-.00x version in the dropdown, and click OK a bunch of times. Then switch the Outliner display mode to ‘Orphan Data’ and click ‘Purge’, or save/reload your file a few times.